# Работа Autowired в Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

Как заставить работать Autowired, не создавая экземпляр класса сервиса из контекста? Использую Спринг Дата без Спринг Бут. 
Класс конфигурации:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class SpringConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.class.getName());
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kvi?useSSL=false");
        dataSource.setUsername("");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibProperties());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("repository", "models");

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;

    }

    private Properties hibProperties() {
        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");

        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.useUnicode", "true");
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding", "UTF-8");
        return jpaProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

Репозиторий:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long>{
}
```

Это сервис:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class PersonService {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    public Iterable<Person> findAll () {
        return personRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Ну и соотвественно есть ентити Person (листинг приводить не буду).
Запуск из класса Main:

```
@ComponentScan
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class);
        AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowireCapableBeanFactory = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        PersonService ps = autowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(PersonService.class);

        List <Person> pers = new ArrayList <>();
        Iterable<Person> findAll = ps.findAll();
        CollectionUtils.addAll(pers, findAll);
        for (Person p : pers) {
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Все работает отлично. Но проблема в том, что каждый раз получать сервис через контекст, как это указано в коде (`PersonService ps = autowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(PersonService.class`);), мягко говоря не удобно.

Comment: Так вы код вынесите из `main` в метод какого-либо бина и в нём используйте `@Autowired`.

Comment: Не совсем Вас понял... Что именно вынести из мейна в другой класс и как этот класс должен выглядеть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аннотация `@Autowired` работает только в бинах.

В `main` имеет смысл только инициализировать контекст и получать из него "корневой" бин. А всю остальную работу делать в этом бине и бинах в него внедрённых.

```
@Component
public class Application {
    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    public void start() {
        for (Person p : personService.findAll()) {
            System.out.println(p);
        }        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class);
        AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowireCapableBeanFactory = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        Application app = autowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(Application.class);

        app.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но по сути у меня так и написано. Вопрос как раз в том и состоит, сто каждый раз, когда мне необходимо обратить к базе данных, мне надо ображаться к фабрике бинов. Значит либо делать синглтон, либо еще одну фабрику, в которой все сервисы будут прописаны... А хотелось бы настроить спринг так, чтобы при обращении к сервису даже путем создания его через оператор new все его переменные инициализировались с помощью @Autowired, ведь сервис то является бином. Вопрос в том, что его создание не удобно тянуть из фабрики.

Comment: Невозможно. Spring'у для внедрения зависимостей необходимо контролировать весь жизненный цикл объекта. Объекты созданные не его фабрикой ему неподконтрольны.

Comment: Ладно, пошли другим путем... Взяли Ваш код, получили исключение Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'util.Application': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'personService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'services.PersonService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: Пометили конфигурацию аннотацией `@ComponentScan` с указанием пакетов, в которых Spring должен искать компоненты, как советует @Bleser?

Comment: Так, вроде разобрался... Спасибо за подсказки. Но есть еще один непонятный момент. Как достать из переменной класса с ленивой инициализацией данные. Стабильно летит соответствующее исключение org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException и я не знаю, как в спринге с этим бороться...

Comment: Если кратко, то либо помечать её как жадную, либо обращаться к ней в пределах той же транзакции, в которой получена вся сущность. Но вообще это объёмный и многогранный вопрос, который поднимался на SO множество раз.

Answer (score 2):

Укажите в аннтоции `@ComponentScan` базовый пакет для сканирования `@ComponentScan("com.company")`. Возможно Spring просто не видит ваши классы.